# Comando para comentar várias linhas no Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Olá

Existe algum atalho para comentar várias linhas no Xcode? Digo, uso hoje `/*...*/`, mas tenho que ir até o começo do bloco parar marcar o início e fazer o mesmo até o final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, vai comentar as linhas selecionadas